# Excel Source full path name is not found in .twb file(in XML structure)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Excel (.xlsx) file located in path C:/Users/name/datasets/products.xlsx
when I use this to build a dashboard and extract the .twb file I get to see Excel path as Data/datasets/products.xlsx in .twb file(in xml structure ) within Connection tag. Why the path is getting changed How can I resolve this as I need a full actual path.

Comment: Isn't it duplicate of your previous question?

Comment: No not duplicate its different question